# How can I use Mathematica to figure out how to efficiently implement gradient and Hessian calculations?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am quite new to Mathematica and mainly use it to check my gradient and Hessian calculations. I figured out how to do this, but the output is only partially helpful. I am not entirely sure if Mathematica can even do this, but most helpful would be if it would help me understand how to efficiently implement the entire Hessian as a function of the defined inputs (e.g. in C++). Can someone explain how to do this, or provide some commands or search terms that I can use to learn more about this? Your advice would be much appreciated!

Marcel

Ps. The gradient and Hessian calculations are attached.
[image]

Comment: Hi Marcel. You say "the output is only partially helpful". Can you show an example of a more helpful output, i.e. an example of something that would be more helpful to you? Right now this question seems hard to answer because we don't know what "helpful" means to you. An answer in terms of C++ is off topic here, btw.

Comment: Your function `func` is quadratic, so gradient and Hessian would be most efficiently implemented by linear algebra operations. Are you only interested in quadratic functions or is this only a toy model? Also, please keep in mind that we like to have _copyable_ code here in order to be able to quickly test and modify it without have to retype everything.

Comment: In priniciple it is possible to generate a C++ code snipped from Mathematica calculations. But for that we'd have to know what you expect as input to the C++ function. Some context might also be helptful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please take the [tour]. A side note, here it's considered helpful to show your own efforts and share your code in a **[well formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) instead of images** or links to external files, so we can quickly **Copy&Paste** your code, test it, and  see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This [question in Meta](https://wolfr.am/v57TjMS9) could be useful.